# Popup window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a controller containing this code:

```
$scope.showSomething = false;
    $scope.doSomething = function () {
        $scope.showSomething = !$scope.showSomething;
};
```

And in html I have this:

```
<div class="row js-static-height-hook">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="interval in consumptionData.keys">
        <div ng-if="consumptionData[interval]" ng-click="doSomething()">
                <modal title="Login form" visible="showSomething">
                        <form role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                      </modal>
            <div class="building-full__consumption-values oed-box-hover-effect">
                <span class="building-full__data-interval">{{consumptionData[interval].label}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are created some "buttons", as many as `ng-repeat` gets. My aim is to add functionality to them using `ng-click`.

I'm trying to make the `modal` appear when a button is clicked and disappear when it is clicked outside of it.

Now it appears on the screen all the time, no matter what I click.Do you know what should I change? Thanks.

Comment: you can use UI Bootstrap, or Angular MaterialJS, in Angular Material you can make a custom dialog which can include your code of the modal in your question. and you can set $mdDialog.clickOutsideToClose(true)
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

Answer (score 0):

What is *visible*? Try using ng-show or ng-if instead. You should share a demo of your issue to better understand.

```
<modal ng-show="showSomething">
    // this will only show the modal if showSomething is true
</modal>
```